# php missing decoding module or problem with newrelic?

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6, newrelic

did anyone met similar output when executing php?
[image]

I met with encrypted code in files, some at our place need ioncube extension for example to work properly

Funny thing, that occurs only in one part of our back office, when disabling newrelic agent in their module, or after removing their module from php.
Other parts of website and back office are working fine.

I wouldn't touch anything, except that (probably newrelic) lately started receiving 503's errors one on of ajax reqeust at back office without any proper error, when newrelic agent is off, ajax request goes through without any error, but other other part of BO is failing then.

I am confused, I would be grateful for any tips!

Tried to update newrelic, same scenario still.

stack: PHP7.1

I asked similar question at newrelic community, for now nothing. I will keep you posted!

Comment: This looks like multi byte UTF-8 characters being shown from something that does not understand the character set, this may help you understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: I get the general thought of above, but what that could have in common with switching newrelic php module, it's not mbstring though =P

Answer (score 0):

ok so I managed to get ajax request back working.. it seems that too many calls off recursive function where generating 503s but still did not figure out:

- why after turning off newrelic agent module php code managed execute successfully (my blind guess something related with module's code segmentation faults, read some stuff on community page)
- problem with wierd encoding / charset on one back office page when disabling newrelic module